# Appending JSON array to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("string");
jsonObj.toString();

"employees":[{"firstname":"stack","lastname":"overflow"}, {"firstname":"Happy","lastname":"Coding"}]
```

How can I append:

```
{"firstname":"Gloomy","lastname":"Sunday"}
```

to above json object

I want to get

```
"employees":[{"firstname":"stack","lastname":"overflow"}, {"firstname":"Happy","lastname":"Coding"}, {"firstname":"Gloomy","lastname":"Sunday"}]

upon jsonObj.toString();
```

Comment: Are you sure the fist code sample produces the string written at the end of it? Where do the data come from?

Answer (score 0):

Please do research this yourself first, this website is not here to do your computer science homework for you. Just cause I need some rep...

```
public class ex{
    void example(){
        try{
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject("[{firstname:stack,lastname:overflow}]");
            JSONObject jobj2 = new JSONObject("[{firstname:Happy,lastname:Coding}]");
            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
            jarray.put(jobj);
            jarray.put(jobj2);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tying to append into existing employees object , not creating new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject("{"firstname":"Gloomy","lastname":"Sunday"}");
jsonObj.append("employees", jo1);
```